# Compatibilidad de Internet Explorer con HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, internet-explorer

Tengo un listado desplegable, al utilizar la emulacion de Edge y 10 funciona sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al utilizar la emulacion de 9, 8 y 7 no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian explicar por que pasa esta situacion y como resolver el problema.

Comment: Intenta agregar `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Continua sin funcionar

Comment: como dice el error IE 8 y versiones mas antiguas no soportan el método `getElementsByClassName()` tendrías que agregar un polyfill o shim para que reemplace la funcionalidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de tiempo googletrasnlateo https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054465/1423096

Internet Explorer 8 y anteriores no son compatibles con `getElementsByClassName()`. Si sólo necesita una solución para IE8, este admite `querySelectorAll()`. Para las versiones de IE más antiguas, debe proporcionar su propia implementación, y para algunos navegadores antiguos que lo admiten también puede usar `evaluate()` que ejecuta expresiones XPath.

Este código proporciona un método `document.getElementsByClassName` si aún no existe utilizando los métodos que [kapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468793/kapa) ha descrito:

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esta etiqueta para que sea compatible con EI

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```